# richfaces 4 client side validation problem

Tags: richfaces, client-side-validation

I have a problem with richfaces client side validation. Here is my xhtml page sample ;

```
<h:form id="deneForm">
<rich:panel>

<h:panelGrid columns="2"> 
<h:inputText value="#{denemeBean.name}" id="name"  required="true" requiredMessage="Not null please">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="8" />
                    <f:validateRequired />
                    <rich:validator />
                </h:inputText>
                <rich:message for="name" />
                <h:outputText value="Email" />

                <h:outputText value="Age" />
                <h:inputText value="#{denemeBean.age}" id="age" required="true" requiredMessage="Not null please">
                    <f:validateLongRange minimum="18" maximum="99"/>
                    <rich:validator />
                </h:inputText>
                <rich:message for="age" />

</h:panelGrid>

<h:commandButton  value="Submit" action="#{denemeBean.success}"> </h:commandButton>
</rich:panel>
    </h:form>
```

when I write values to textboxes, i can see validation errors, but when i press Submit button, client side script isnt activated and form is submitted anyway. Server side validation starts and says "Not null please". How can I trigger client side validation on pressing submit button?

using : mojarra 2, richfaces 4

Comment: This is an interesting question. The implementation above mirrors the way I've been using Richfaces client validation very closely. The user gets instant feedback on validation when they interact with the components and I rely on server side validation when they submit the form. The presentation of errors is the same either way. It sounds like you would also like client validation to occur onsubmit, presumably to avoid the cost of a page load? Other than that I'm not sure why server side validation isn't acceptable when the user submits the form?

Comment: Hi Dave, although client side validation is not very safety, I make both client and server side validation. Yes, because of less server usage. By the way i think i solved it by replacing h:commandbutton with ajax:commandbutton, i overlooked it

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't realize that a4j:commandButton added support for form level client side validation. Can you post your own solution as an answer if it is working so that we can all benefit?

Answer (score 0):

Client-side validation doesn't get invoked when clicking a button. This feature is not supported yet.

Comment: hi Max Katz, i am newbie for richfaces but i think replacing '<h:commandButton  value="Submit"..' with '<a4j:commandButton  value="Submit' solved my problem. Is your answer also valid for richfaces 4 ?